# can't open "select" tag inside royalslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, tags

I have select with options inside slider royalslider.

This block are inside royalslider.

```
<select name="filter-color">
       <option value="red">red</option>
       <option value="green">green</option>
       <option value="blue">blue</option>
       <option value="white">white</option>
</select>
```

When i click on select it doesn't opening.

I also try this javascript:

```
<script>
 $(function () {
  $("select[name='filter-color']").on('click', function(){
  console.log('filter-color click');
 })
}
</script>
```

and it display 'filter-color click' in console. That mean the event "click" is binding and working with "select".

What can be wrong? Why "select" doesn't opening?

Comment: Could you post a link to a jsFiddle?

Comment: sounds like a hidden overflow issue. Please create a demo that replicates the problem

Comment: well you said it wouldn't open, but now you say it does. We can't guess without being able to replicate problem

Comment: Thank everyone for help. I decide this problem using this http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/how-to-prevent-dragging-over-specific-elements.